# how to deserialize different JSON structures to the same C# class

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

Lets say I have the first json.

```
{
"TestA": [{
    "Name": "Adam",
    "Address": "test address"
}] }
```

And second json schema is:

```
{
"TestB": [{
    "Name": "Sam",
    "Address": "test address2",
    "param1" : "test param1"
}] }
```

How can i Deserialize these two json object into one class?

Comment: `public class Person{ string Name { get; set; } string Address { get; set; } string param1 { get; set; } }` and `JsonConvert.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Obj[]>>(json);` ?

Comment: If during deserialization you know what schema you receive, then its probably better not to deserialize two different JSON schemas to the same class. Just create three classes: for case 1, for case 2 and for inner object (`Name`, `Address`, etc). Then, `testA.TestA` and `testB.TestB` will return your objects. If you don't know which one you receive (for example, two different HTTP requests to the same endpoint), then just use `Dictionary`, just like in the comment above.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev  : I don't want to use dictionary . I want a generic class which can provide me result (name,address) in a object (if this response is coming from two different HTTP request.